# class level getintent

Tags: java, android

When I get my intent from one activity to other one I get this

```
" E/AndroidRuntime(686): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.swaam.mytextapp/com.swaam.mytextapp.Chat}: java.lang.NullPointerException"
```

It only occur when I getintent() in a class level; if I get it in oncreate() it works fine.
so my question is why could I not getintent() in a class level? Here is my code:

```
Intent getchatnum=getIntent();
String chatnumber=getchatnum.getStringExtra("number");
```

Comment: Class object is created in your second activity?

Comment: Its better if you post possible code.

Comment: What do you mean by `get my intent from one activity to other`? Please show the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
getIntent();
```

works only in a Activity which is alive... but when you do it before `onCreate()` (your case) its obvious that an Exception will be thrown since the activity has not been created yet..